# Problems with RenderAction in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, renderaction

I wanted use MVC and renderpartial to generate a menu but but could not get it to work, and from what I read it seemed maybe RenderAction would be more suitable. Still I have not gotten it to work.

What I intended to do was create a controller that selects certain articles from a database that will act as categories (this is put into HomeController):

```
public ActionResult MenuController()
    {
        var movies = from m in db.Art
                     where m.ArtikelNr.StartsWith("Webcat")
                     select m;
        return View(movies);
    }
```

And then send that information to a view:

```
@model IEnumerable<xxxx.Models.Art>
@{
Layout = null;
}

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Benämning_10)</li>
}
```

This works when I just run it as a normal controller and view, it returns a list of what I want. But if I want to call it from _layout.cshtml (because this menu should appear on every page) like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">@Html.RenderAction(MenuController)</div>
```

Then it generates the following error:

```
CS0103: The name 'MenuController' does not exist in the current context
```

What is the proper way of calling an action/view/whatever from the _layout.cshtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
@Html.RenderAction("_MenuController")
```

and be sure that you have a working rule in your Global.asax

As suggested in another answer would be better to use

```
return PartialView();
```

I also suggest you to use the [ChildActionOnlyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx) to be sure that this action will never be called as a standard action.

So something like that:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _MenuController()
{
    var movies = from m in db.Art
                 where m.ArtikelNr.StartsWith("Webcat")
                 select m;
    return PartialView(movies);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips, I have implemented them (still getting error CS1502), but what do you mean with having a working rule in global.asax? Rule for what?

Comment: I would just like to say I was able to get it working now, for some reason it would not work unless it was typed like this, can anyone explain to me why this works? `<div id="sidebar">@{ Html.RenderAction("MenuController"); }</div>`

Comment: For the global.asax I was suggesting to be sure to che ck the rule in case you have modified the standard rule (/{controller}/{action}/{id}) or it would not find the action. For the second tips you are excuting a function. look here for more info http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MenuController");}
```

or

```
@Html.Action("MenuController")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

@Html.RenderAction("MenuController")

You've forgotten quotes around your string parameter

Comment: Thanks, that's true, a bit embarrasing. But still that now generates another error: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="sidebar">@Html.RenderAction("_MenuController")</div>
```

Quotes around your action name :) It might also be good practice to return a partial view:

```
return PartialView(movies);
```